# how to rearrange method access modifier using regex

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube-scan, regex-group

I am new to regex .
I was trying to rearrange the method access modifier using regex for sonar [Rule](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:ModifiersOrderCheck?layout=false)

```
(public|protected|private)|(abstract|static)|(final)|(volatile)|(synchronized)|(native)|(strictfp)
```

having input example as 
 `static public void main(String[] args)` 
 and then replacing using  
`$1$2$3$4$5$6$7` 
 but i am getting same result .

Output should be in correct access modifer order like first public then static :
`public static void main (String[] args)`
method signature should follow order :
`public or protected or private` then if applicable 
`abstract or static` then if applicable 
`final` then if applicable 
`volatile` then if applicable 
`synchronized` then if applicable 
`native` then if applicable 
`stictfp`

[*RegexExampleLink*](https://regex101.com/r/GcZucI/4)

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: *"...and then replacing using `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7` but i am getting same result..."* Well, that makes sense, since you've echoed the capture groups in exactly the same order. Perhaps you wanted to change the order. But you'll need to do a much more thorough job describing what you're trying to do, and show more of your attempt (code, sample inputs, expected outputs), for us to be able to help you. Also beware that using regex on something like program source code is almost **always** a recipe for frustration and unintended side-effects. Use a parser.

Comment: i updated my question i want static public to change into public static as its correct access modifier order for java method

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am just trying to rearrange the method access modifier in correct order as per sonar , not changing any modifier . according to me it should not cause any side-effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern of the form `(…)|(…)|(…)|…` specifies alternatives, whereas only one has to match. So your pattern is matching exactly one keyword at a time, having one group containing the matching keyword and all other groups being empty. Then, when you replace that match with `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7` you are replacing the keyword with itself, the other groups not having any effect. Applying the operation repeatedly still has no effect.

So you need a pattern matching the entire sequence of keywords, filling the groups whose keywords are present. To do this, encompass your regex in another group with the `+` quantifier, to match at least one keyword, but as many as present. The good thing about the capturing groups in a repeating group is that they keep remembering their previous match if they don’t match in the next repetition. So after identifying a match of the repeating group, each sub-group has captured a keyword, if there was one in the sequence.

So a resulting pattern can look like

```
(?:\b((?:public|protected|private)\s+)|((?:abstract|static)\s+)|(final\s+)|((?:volatile|synchronized)\s+)|((?:native|strictfp)\s+))+
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/xXs54Q/1)

Here, I identified more mutual exclusive keywords, reducing the number to five groups. I included the subsequent white-space in the group (using a sub-pattern like `((?:keyword1|keyword2)\s+)`, listing the alternatives in a non-capturing group). That way, there will be correct spacing in the replacement. I added a word boundary at the beginning (`\b`) to ensure that there are no false matches (e.g. the word `nonstatic`). A word boundary after the keyword is already implied due to the mandatory white-space.

In Java code:

```
String in = "synchronized public final static native void main(String[] args)";
String out = in.replaceAll(
      "(?:\\b"
    +   "((?:public|protected|private)\\s+)|((?:abstract|static)\\s+)|"
    +   "(final\\s+)|((?:volatile|synchronized)\\s+)|((?:native|strictfp)\\s+)"
    + ")+",
  "$1$2$3$4$5"
);

System.out.println(out);// public static final synchronized native void main(String[] args)
```

---

But note that this has limitations. To the Java language, annotations are modifiers, thus can be freely mixed with the keyword modifiers, e.g. `static @Deprecated public`. Since annotations have a recursive grammar (annotations may contain annotations, but even simpler cases like nested constant expressions or array initializers may have different depths), it is impossible to parse all valid annotation values via a single regular expression. So the above solution only handles keywords and regardless of how many annotation cases you may add, you always have to make a cut somewhere, considering everything else as not supported.

Comment: I keep reading [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) once in a while to remember the rules, but complicated to remember forever

Comment: @Holger thanks this is what i was looking for , currently in am not considering annotation case , i will mark it answered.

Comment: Eugene, thanks for link , i will go over the it, to better understanding how ?: with + behave in case of group.

Answer (score -1):

What you have is basically what you need, you just need to put the pieces together. The regex should be

```
(public|protected|private)|(abstract|static)|(final)|(volatile)|(synchronized)|(native)|(strictfp)
```

The *capturing group indices* are what determines what should go where. If you can capture the entire method signature, ie.

```
static public void main(String[] args)
```

as a String, then the regex above will capture `public` in capturing group 1 and `static` in capturing group 2. [Try it out here!](https://regex101.com/r/WYfDn6/1)

Use java.util.regex.{[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html),[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)} to get the capture groups, then rearrange them manually, making sure to use [String.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove extra whitespace.

Here's a worked solution

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Signature {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // slightly more complex example to show off capabilities of method
    String oldSignature = "synchronized static final native public void barFooer(int foo, double bar)";

    // echo to user
    System.out.printf("%nOriginal method signature:%n    %s%n%n", oldSignature);

    // group number (          1             ) (        2      ) (  3  ) (   4    ) (     5      ) (   6  ) (   7    )
    String regex = "(public|protected|private)|(abstract|static)|(final)|(volatile)|(synchronized)|(native)|(strictfp)";

    // create regex.Pattern and regex.Matcher objects
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(oldSignature);

    // array to hold signature "groups" in correct order
    String[] groups = new String[7];

    // int to hold end of last matched group
    int endOfLastGroup = -1;

    while (mat.find()) {
      for (int gg = 1; gg <= 7; ++gg) {

        // get the new matched group and any previous match in this group
        String newGroup = mat.group(gg);
        String oldGroup = groups[gg-1];

        // where does the new matched group end?
        int endOfNewGroup = mat.end();

        // did we find a new match in this group?
        if (newGroup != null) {

          // cannot have, for instance, both "public" and "private"
          if (oldGroup != null) {
            System.err.printf("Error! Signature cannot contain both '%s' and '%s'!%n", newGroup.trim(), oldGroup.trim());
            return;
          }

          // otherwise, new group found!
          groups[gg-1] = newGroup;

          // find furthest-right matched group end
          if (mat.end() > endOfLastGroup)
            endOfLastGroup = mat.end();
    } } }

    // new signature will be constructed with a StringBuilder
    StringBuilder newSignature = new StringBuilder("");

    // add groups to new signature in correct order
    for (String group : groups) {
      if (group != null) {
        newSignature.append(group.trim());
        newSignature.append(" ");
    } }

    // finally, add the return type, method name, arguments, etc.
    newSignature.append(oldSignature.substring(endOfLastGroup).trim());

    // echo to user
    System.out.printf("New method signature:%n    %s%n%n", newSignature.toString());

  }

}
```

Sample output:

```
17:34 |aww@airy test| javac Signature.java 

17:35 |aww@airy test| java Signature

Original method signature:
    synchronized static final native public void barFooer(int foo, double bar)

New method signature:
    public static final synchronized native void barFooer(int foo, double bar)
```

This code is also available at the following gist:
https://gist.github.com/awwsmm/85575d2756f69b95564ff11b8ee105fd

Comment: i was thinking to do it like `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexForMethodSignature, Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputMethodSignature);
  String result = matcher.replaceAll("$1\\s$2\\s$3\\s$4\\s$6\\s$7\\s");` but not able to capture all group as part of single match.

Comment: Hi @SandeepChauhan. Not sure what you're referencing there, but I added a solution as I would code it. Let me know if you have any questions about my solution.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? This answers the question asked, unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: i have not downvoted it. i appreciate the effort you have put in, 
but if i have to use the for and while loop , then i can simply used some list with proper access modifer order and have
broken the old method signature using split method and rearranged by comparing against list of access modifer.
what i wanted was using regex $1$2 feature to replace it in one go using replacAll method.
like in this simple [Example Link](https://regex101.com/r/JxRhSC/1/)

Comment: I think it would be very difficult to do it the way you want to. The variable identifiers (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) only give the nth "match". These are equivalent to the individual "loops" of the `while` loop in my solution. Without any other information (ie. which group a given match actually matched), it's not possible to put them in the order you want.

Comment: I have to admit that when I started writing [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954445/2711488), I also thought that this had to be very complicated, but after rewriting my solution three times, I ended up with a dead simple solution, close to the question’s original pattern, as I realized that the way, capturing groups within a repeating group work, plays perfectly into this use case. So I also learned a useful thing today…